# How to change Curl command to Python3 by request lib?

Tags: python

I use curl commnad to get my data and command like follow :

```
curl "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/6303943f-5acf-4f75-aa26-b6694bfece1d?" \
      --request GET \
      --get \
      --data "subscription-key=f01b9c74cad740b2bbad33fccf017e13" \
      --data "verbose=true" \
      --data-urlencode "q=請幫我搜尋一個禮拜的天氣"
```

But, I want to ask how to change this command to python by `requests` lib?
Have any one help me ?

Comment: Here is a site that does that, https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```py
import requests

url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/6303943f-5acf-4f75-aa26-b6694bfece1d?&subscription-key=f01b9c74cad740b2bbad33fccf017e13&verbose=true&q=請幫我搜尋一個禮拜的天氣"

payload = 'subscription-key=f01b9c74cad740b2bbad33fccf017e13&verbose=true&q=%u8ACB%u5E6B%u6211%u641C%u5C0B%u4E00%u500B%u79AE%u62DC%u7684%u5929%u6C23'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Note : Postman can use for converting any kind of request to different language.

[image]